# YA Series about high-schooler fighting aliens that look like werewolves

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I saw books from this series near the end of elementary school. I never actually read it but the aliens pictured on the front covers looked like wolfmen, and the little I remember from the blurbs on the back cover said something about them infiltrating a high school (I think).

Somehow a girl in said high school knew of them (I got the impression no one else did, though I'm at a loss to explain why) and made it her mission to expose them before they could kill her.

I think one of the covers showed an alien jumping a teenager (presumably the heroine) at a swimming pool if that helps.

Comment: Can you add any info about the characters? Perhaps this checklist will help you to refine your question; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the Private School series by Steven Charles?

The cover of book 4 ( [https://www.amazon.com/Skeleton-Private-School-Steven-Charles/dp/0671603299](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671603299) ) shows a creature pulling a girl into a swimming pool.

This series was the answer for a similar question elsewhere ( http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=2320 ), where the moderator provided book descriptions mentioning the alien wolfbeasts.

Comment: that looks about right.